# Youtube embedded player video size issue

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api, flash-builder

We have implemented embedded youtube player in our flash application which is written in action script 3.
We are facing a issue with the display of video. After clicking on play button the video size is displaying 1/4 of the display and shifting to the top left corner of the player display leaving the remaining space as blank.

Reference used for implementing embedded youtube player.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference

Kindly suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Use [**`edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42470969/edit). Show minimum code we can use to recreate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the Iframe API itself, in setting the player size, you should use this:

```
player.setSize(width:Number, height:Number):Void
```

It sets the size in pixels of the player. This method should be used instead of setting the width and height properties of the MovieClip. Note that this method does not constrain the proportions of the video player, so you will need to maintain a 4:3 aspect ratio. The default size of the chromeless SWF when loaded into another SWF is 320px by 240px and the default size of the embedded player SWF is 480px by 385px.

Or you can change the width and height value inside the . You can try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G5GhH/38/).